# Assembly instruction imulq for short type source

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm studying System Programming using book "CS:APP".
In this book, practice problem 3.42 is as below

```c
 struct ACE {
    short v;
    struct ACE *p;
 };
 short test(struct ACE *ptr)
```

When the code for fun is compiled, gcc generates the following assembly code:

```
//short test(struct ACE *ptr)
// ptr in %rdi

test :
  movl $1 %eax
  jmp   .L2
.L3:
  imulq (%rdi), %rax
  movq 2(%rdi), %rdi
.L2:
 testq %rdi, %rdi
 jne  .L3
 rep;ret
```

At this assembly code, I 've thought that imulq instruction need to be changed to imulw.
Since struct ACE type will play as a linked list, and this test function calculate the multiplication of each value of list. But value of list has type short which is 2 bytes, I think imulq instruction need to be changed to imulw.

Comment: You haven't shown us the C definition of `test`.

Comment: The generated code you have there is indeed very strange.  Both the `imulq` and the `movq 2(%rdi), %rdi` are suspicious.  What is the C source of this?

Comment: Books have bugs, this one has rather a lot of them.  [Look here](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html), add if necessary.

Comment: Is this the output that gcc *actually* produces, or what the book *says* it produces?  If you have the notorious global third edition mentioned in Hans's link, then you should ignore what the book says (and perhaps throw it away completely, or at least tear out all the pages with exercises).  There are dozens of other questions on this site with people getting confused by the flat-out lies in that edition.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57999595/634919 for more absurdities from this book.

Comment: And more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955902/is-it-possible-to-use-a-register-other-than-rax-for-returning-from-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772527/i-correctly-guessed-missing-part-of-a-function-but-gcc-generated-assembly-code?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116201/why-is-it-necessary-to-add-a-bias-to-the-dividend-for-signed-division-by-a-power https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072299/assembly-instruction-imulq-for-short-type-source

Comment: Yup, if this is actually a product of linked-list elements, it should be `imulw`. (Or if the result should be a wider int to avoid overflow, a separate load and then dword or qword imul). You're right, `imulq` would load 6 bytes of padding / garbage.  Also, it should be `mov 8(%rdi), %rdi` because alignof(pointer) == 8 in the x86-64 System V ABI, and the struct-layout rules follow that.  (unless the struct used `__attribute__((packed))`)

Comment: Actually, if you want to be totally technical, it's not strictly wrong because the low 16 bits of RAX (i.e. AX) will have the correct `short` return value.  [The low N bits of a multiply result only depend on the low N bits of either input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in), so high garbage won't disturb the `short` at the bottom of the register.  x86-64 System V return values are allowed to have high garbage.  GCC won't make this asm, but a DeathStation 9000 compiler with different struct layout could!